# Extraer numeros de un arreglo para hacer otro

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando a base de un vector generado aleatoriamente, realizar otro que como valores tenga la cantidad de veces que se repite cada valor en el orden que estan, por poner un ejemplo, tengo el vector vi[10]={2,6,8,8,4,2,3,1,4,2} entonces he pensado que una solución podría ser extraer cada valor del vector recorriendolo y que cada vez que encuentre el mismo valor, aumente un contador pues tengo que lograr que el programa logre siguiendo el ejemplo: el 2 se repite 3 veces, el 6 una vez, el 8 dos veces, el 4 dos veces, el 3 una vez y el 1 una vez y que mi vector resultante quede como [3,1,2,2,1,1]

Alguien sabe cómo podría hacer esto o si quiera si sirve mi teoría de solución? O que otra solución podría haber para esto?  Estoy en c++

Comment: En realidad no veo la relacion entre la explicacion que das de la solucion y el
array de solucion que colocas de ejemplo. Pasando de eso, puede que te interese
ver como usar `std::map`.

Comment: Copia tu vector a un vector temporal. Luego tienes un `for` principal` y un `for` secundario, es decir, dentro del for principal. Por cada elemento que leas en el for principal buscas ese valor en el for secundario a partir del índice + 1 y vas sumando 1 por cada valor que encuentres igual y reemplazas su valor a -1. El for principal debe ignorar los que encuentre en -1. Cuando salgas del for secundario pones el contador en el vector resultante. Debes llevar un índice para este y aumenta luego del for secundario

Comment: Es prácticamente tu teoría.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil será usar un mapa, siempre y cuando conservar el orden no sea importante:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int valores[10] = {2, 6, 8, 8, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2};

    std::map<int, int> recuentos;

    for (const auto &valor : valores)
    {
        auto [posicion, insertado] = recuentos.emplace(valor, 0);
        ++posicion->second;
    }

    for (const auto [valor, recuento] : recuentos)
        std::cout << valor << " aparece " << recuento << " veces\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9fa4MwEH82n@LoYFSMw7ZjDLV@EdeHI6YloElIYl@KX33uorN7GYTjfnf5/TlhbS561Ld5flFa9GMnoVbGBydxaNjfbEDbMKZ0gAGV3qfswZKI7tgbJ317KC5whseRwweHz@W9cyB44nBY@6liLPGhK0sSq4nMgUoDTopR6mB83F@Ng70w2gfAMRh4XQyg3IxSlpBzsuxaa7wSyugo5KUL2JmY4in4Jgfbo5D7hcyhSCviZtnGyxsvyauj6fSPd/tL2/QuFOOpTUHWY4QZA9T1GjA2O0CL9E9SR3BjrKs7zf2X3sVbnQyj01BUbJrnb3Ht8ebnnETPIsuO@AM)</kbd>.

Si conservar el orden es realmente importante, no hay un contenedor asociativo que garantice conservar el orden; dado que no podemos apoyarnos en el truco del contenedor asociativo hay que contar número a número siempre y cuando el número no se haya contado antes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int valores[10] = {2, 6, 8, 8, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2};

    std::vector<int> recuentos;

    // Para cada valor...
    for (const auto &valor : valores)
        // ... buscamos si el valor apareció antes en la colección...
        if (std::find(std::cbegin(valores), &valor, valor) == &valor)
            // ... y si no apareció antes, contamos cuantas veces aparece.
            recuentos.push_back(std::count(valores, valores + 10, valor));

    for (const auto &valor : recuentos)
        std::cout << valor << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BboMwEETP@CtWqtSAcCpIq6oikB@pqsoxhlglNrLXuUT59VKMcdpTJR9mxztvlo/jlg9M9dP0IBUfXCugltqiEex8IL/eRXDU5q/Dhl4biad5jUiFcGZSpRm5ksRPFzZoI@x7WXxAA9cdhVcKb8t7oTCPzxTKoG97QhKLbVWFknrOH8AI7oRCbf1vpw2kXCuLwBxqeFzwUMWajCSJ7CBdKJ1UbVD8KPr5qLhE1xwNsQyaZnV8Prk3Po3Onj6PjH@tGO0URgqNnZBDWURU9u@Vd7LviUiEug5pLzaw8Qgj0BkFxZ7cpumbdwPr7bSdIw3P8x37AQ)</kbd>.